# Initiate and return node property if it does not exist using a single Cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm looking for a **single** Cypher query that will increment an integer node parameter and return the value while initiating it to `0` in case if it does not exist.

Something like following pseudo-Cypher:

```
MATCH (n:Order)
IF n.product_count IS NULL THEN n.product_count = 0 // this line is what I need
SET n.product_count = n.product_count + 1
RETURN n.product_count
```

I was able to put together a query with a `FOREACH` statement that gets the job done, but this seems hacky and not appropriate for my use case:

```
MATCH (n:Order)
WHERE id(n) = 9503
FOREACH ( i in (CASE WHEN n.product_count IS NULL THEN [1] ELSE [] END) | SET n.product_count = 0 )
SET n.product_count = n.product_count + 1
RETURN n.product_count;
```

How would this be done the right way?

Note: the `Order` node is very complex and contains many other properties, so `MERGE` statment in this case would be highly undesired.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Neo4j provides a useful function for situations like this called **coalesce**.

Coalesce takes any number of arguments, and returns the first that is not NULL. In the case where all arguments are NULL, it simply returns NULL.

So, for example:

```
coalesce(NULL, 1) // equates to 1
coalesce("hello", 6) // equates to "hello"
coalesce(NULL, "world", NULL) // equates to "world"
coalesce(NULL, NULL) // equates to NULL
```

Thus, your query would look something like this:

```
MATCH (n:Order)
SET n.product_count = coalesce(n.product_count, 0) + 1
RETURN n.product_count
```

Here's the official documentation on coalesce:

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-functions-scalar.html#functions-coalesce

Comment: Good stuff, thanks! Somehow it did not occur to me to use `coalesce` here.